# Is there an easy algorithm for generating a random distribution within a range but skewed toward the ends?

Tags: distributions, algorithms

Is there an easy algorithm for generating a random distribution within a range but skewed toward the ends?

I guess I am looking for some random distribution $x$ that is parameterized with some parameter $p \in [0,1]$ that might have the following properties, or at least something close to it:

- $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ (I can always transform to some other range)
- $E(x) = 0$
- $E(x^2) = \frac{3-2p}{3}$

so that $p=0$ corresponds to a point distribution at the ends and $p=1$ corresponds to a uniform distribution.

Comment: There are myriad possibilities.  For instance, you could start with any finite number of predefined distributions with these properties and take any mixture of them you wish.  The issue, then, is not *how* to generate such variates, but *why*: what is it you are attempting to model, learn, or decide based on this process?  What guidance can you give to help pin down an appropriate answer?

Comment: While there's nothing in the problem statement that seems to require symmetry I suspect you may have it in mind - do you intend to have symmetric distributions or is that not a consideration?  (I think whuber makes a good point -- it's easy enough to do, but what's this for?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wait -- I just thought of something:

- generate $u$ from a uniform distribution $\in [-1,1]$
- calculate $x = |u|^p \operatorname{sgn} u$ for $0 < p \leq1$ (also include $p=0$ by defining $x=1$ if $u=0$), which yields a uniform distribution for $p=1$ and a point distribution for $p=0$.

Not sure of its variance, but the general behavior is what I'm looking for.

cdf here for p=0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0

[image]

Comment: If you generate a random variable that way, it'll have zero "skewness" if that's what you're interested in. Or were you referring to something else when you wrote "skewed toward the ends"?

Comment: Btw, if $X=|U|^p sgn(U)$ then the distribution of $\frac 1 2 (X+1)$ is given by a Beta(1/p, 1). Thus, $X$ is just a shifted and scaled version of Beta.

Comment: sorry, I'm not sure what word I should use then, it has nothing to do with the third moment.

Comment: I guess you're referring to the tails of the distribution then. In that case, I think you had the right idea. A Beta(1/p,1/p) distribution moved to the interval [-1, 1] is probably your best bet. I believe your algorithm generates exactly that.

Comment: I'm looking at the wikipedia articles on [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) and the [incomplete beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function) and I'm confused about the $1/p$ bit; if I divide my function into positive and negative halves (flip a coin to determine which), then it looks more like Beta(p,1) in order to bias the distribution towards $x=1$. Did I miss something? Somehow I am confused about the independent and dependent axes of the graph....

Comment: ok, looks like the $1/p$ is correct and $E(x^2) = \frac{1}{1+2p}$ for my function (analytically from information on variance and mean of $I_x(\frac{1}{p},1)$, matches sample mean and variance of empirically-generated samples)

Comment: I think you got what I was suggesting but in case I wasn't totally clear, it's this: Let $Z$ come from a $Beta(\frac 1 p, \frac 1 p)$ distribution. Then, set $X = 2Z - 1$. $X$ will have a distribution with mean, $E(X)=E(2Z-1)=2E(Z)-1=2 (1/p)/(1/p + 1/p) - 1=0$ and variance, $Var(X)=Var(2Z-1)=2^2 Var(Z)=4 (1/p)^2/((4/p^2)(2/p+1))=\frac p {2+p}$

Comment: how is $Beta(\frac{1}{p}, \frac{1}{p})$ more appropriate than $Beta(\frac{1}{p}, 1)$? just curious.

Comment: If the two parameters are the same, then the distribution will be symmetric. And as p->0, all of the weight will go to the end points. With $Beta(\frac 1 p, 1)$, you get a distribution that's negatively skewed. It'll have a mode at it's right endpoint and equal zero at it's left. Also the mean won't be zero after you do the $2z - 1$ transformation.

Comment: yeah, but I can get symmetric behavior via the $|u|^p \operatorname{sgn} u$ behavior, so that the beta function just dictates what's in each half.